# 'jupyter-notebook' command not working after installing Anaconda

Tags: command-line, bashrc, jupyter

After installing Anaconda and following the installation page, I have run into an issue that requires me to go to the bin in order to use the `jupyter-notebook` command. I found the this working with one of the comments, from Little Bobby Tables, on the top post from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675907/how-to-run-conda

With that said, it reset after I closed my shell. So I checked my `.bashrc` to check that it was set up for `$HOME/anaconda3/bin`. It seems as though it worked, as this is what's at the bottom:

```
__conda_setup="$('/home/.../anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/.../anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/.../anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/.../anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

So what is it that I'm missing? If it's in my `.bashrc` file, why is the command `jupyter-notebook` not running? I followed the installation instructions, as well am able to use the note book if I go into my anaconda3 folder and run `source bin/activate` every time.

Thank you for any and all assistance!